# Hibernate Criteria only returning partial results

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

Hi I'm trying to do a query with Hibernate Criteria and it is only returning part of the query.

Here's my Entity classes

```
class DataStructureEntity
    DataStructureStatus statusId
    //fields, getters, setters omitted for space reasons
}

class DataStructureStatus {
    public static final String STATUS_TYPE_PUBLISHED = "Published";
    public static final String STATUS_TYPE_DRAFT = "Draft";

    private String statusName;
    //other fields, getters, setters omitted for space reasons
}
```

And here is my query

```
DetachedCriteria dctr = DetachedCriteria.forClass(DataStructureEntity.class);
dctr.createCriteria("statusId").add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("statusName",   
    DataStructureStatus.DRAFT_ID), (Restrictions.eq("statusName", 
    DataStructureStatus.PUBLISHED_ID))));
```

And to execute the query:

```
return dctr.getExecutableCriteria(getSession()).setFirstResult(firstRow).setMaxResults(maxResults).list();
```

I need this query to return DataStructureEntity objects where DataStructureEntity.statusId.statusName is equal to DataStructureStatus.DRAFT_ID or DataStructureStatus.DRAFT_PUBLISHED. However, the query only returns objects where DataStructureEntity.statusId.statusName is equal to DRAFT_PUBLISHED.

Can anyone see why that is? Also would it make if a difference if the query is written as HQL? If so, how would this be written as HQL?

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: So, is is `statusId` or `dataStructureStatus`? Is it `id` or `statusName`? Is it `DRAFT_ID` or `STATUS_TYPE_DRAFT`? There are so many incoherences in the code and explanations you give that you should first fix these issues, and then we'll try to find the mistake.

Comment: Sorry about that. I should be fixed now :-)

Comment: Your code still has inconsistencies. You're using constants that don't exist. Don't ask us to comment on a fake, imaginary problem. Show us your REAL code. The one which compiles, runs, and shows the actual problem.